# Какие файлы и данные просить у заказчика для внесения правок на сайт, написанный на laravel

Tags: php, laravel, фриланс

Проблема: На данный момент имею опыт работы только с локальным сервером и не представляю, что просить у заказчика для внесения правок на его сайт, написанный на Laravel, который уже находится в общем доступе.
В моей больной фантазии, заказчик должен просто перекинуть мне папку с проектом, затем я запускаю проект на локалке, вношу изменения и кидаю заказчику измененную папку с проектом, которую он сам загрузит куда надо. Уверен, что в реальности, все по-другому. Спрашивать у самого заказчика боюсь, так как он скорее всего посчитает меня некомпетентным и откажется от услуги.
Вопрос: Какие файлы и данные могут пригодится при работе с сайтом на Laravel?

Comment: _он скорее всего посчитает меня некомпетентным и откажется от услуги._ И правильно сделает. Не надо браться за то, что не умеете делать. Вы сперва сами выгрузите на хостинг сайт, настройте его и т.п., а потом уже берите заказы

Answer (score 1):

Комментарий был оставлен верный. Но все же.
Вам нужно получить ftp доступ к хостингу на котором лежит сам сайт и доступ в бд, в основном это MySQL(PMA) или PostgreSQL.
И именно с ftp сервера вы и получите файлы сайта.

В лучшем случае у заказчика должен быть репозиторий откуда вы возьмете код и будете с ним оперировать на выделенной вам ветке(зависит от git flow самого проекта)

Так что просите репозиторий, если нет, то доступы на прямую на хостинг